# Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Error when getting current notification event ID (state=42000,code=40000)

Tags: beeline

I am exporting a hive table to hdfs using beeline,I am getting error as

> Error: Error while compiling statement:
>
> FAILED: SemanticException Error when getting current notification event ID (state=42000,code=40000)"

Comment: I am using dataproc for above query,is there any hive/beeline configuration required

Comment: Fix formatting.